# How to iterate JSON nested array in REACT JS API call?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, api, axios

I have my **REACT** JS client side and php API on server side. My API call fetches the **JSON** data in the below format(I tried it on **POSTMAN**):

```js
{
    "records": {
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            }
        ],
        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions"
            }
        ],
        
         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This above code is like an array which contains arrays of each company's items. Some Company has *2 items, some has 3 and some has only 1 item*. Now I have my **REACT** JS where I wanna call the php API and save this above JSON data **in such a format that I save each Company's items separately in separate arrays** (dynamically).

I need to iterate through the above JSON data and **split it into as many arrays as the unique Companies present**. Like above data has has **3 distinct companies' items** so I wanna split this JSON into 3 different arrays but if I had **15** different Companies then I would like to split and save it in **15 different arrays**. My rough idea of REACT API call using **AXIOS** is below:

```js
  axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/show_cart.php', 
     {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } )
    .then(response => {

    //I need to know what to write here to save the data in my required format

      })
     .catch(error => {
     if (error) {
       console.log("REACT Error. Cannot show cart items");  }
       });
```

Please I need Help how to **dynamically** save my items (Grouped By Company Names) in separate arrays for each Company. **Please Help!**

P.S. **mySQL** Group BY query doesn't help here. I just want help in React API call. Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:**
I want to store the data in arrays(named on Company Names)
like array **Masterautomotives[ ]** should have this data below:

```js
 [
                {
                    "SparePartID": "43",
                    "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                    "Price": "4500",
                    "VendorID": "48",
                    "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
                },
                {
                    "SparePartID": "45",
                    "Name": "Lights",
                    "Price": "2300",
                    "VendorID": "48",
                    "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
                }
  ]
```

And Array **RepairSolutions[ ]** should have following data:

```js
 [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions"
            }
  ]
```

and so on for rest of the Companies whoever is being fetched from API call.

Comment: provide an example of what data structure you want got

Comment: @RomanUnt I have edit the code to provide example. I hope this is what u want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with this data? Are you saving them directly to the state? You basically have access to it in your desired format directly from the API response, just as properties of response.records. I can't think of what you would need arrays separately put into the state for, so it may make more sense to just save the entire records object to the state and then access the desired company's data using state.records["Company name"], which will return exactly the data structure you're looking for.  You can then map over the object's keys and in turn over each array contained within to render all of the products grouped by company.

```
  axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/show_cart.php', 
     {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } )
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
         records: response.records
      })

      })
     .catch(error => {
     if (error) {
       console.log("REACT Error. Cannot show cart items");  }
       });
```

And then you can render lists of each company's parts:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.state.records).map((company, i) => (
        <div key={company}>
          <h2>{company}</h2>
          <ul>
           {this.state.records[company].map((product, i) => (
              <li>{product["Name"]} - ${product["Price"]}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

See this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/EJMjmB).

Comment: Thanks alot. this is what I wanted. And why I wanted the data like in separate arrays is because at the next order processing step I want to create each Company's orders separately. So for that order creation, can I still use this way like **this.state.records[company]** ?

Comment: Exactly.  To be clear the company parameter used there is only accessible in the map function for the object's keys, but all the data is always available at this.state.records["company name"].

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it should help you

```
.then(response => {
    let companies = [];
    let companiesData = response.data.records;;
    for (let company in companiesData)
    {
      companies.push(companiesData[company])
    }
    console.log(companies); 
})
```

Comment: short version of code is    let compaines = Object.values(response.data.records);

Comment: Thanks alot. This answers my question too.